# SCAM TOKEN HELP!

Tags: metamask, wallets, addresses, scam

I'll start by saying that I came across a scam project and I can't switch to pancakeswap from this scam token to bnb. Is there a chance to get out of this token?
address token: 0x6355C0E051aC095E7d55b10C3d77dFadd2c1F136
blockchain: BEP20

Comment: Add more details to your question.

Comment: Andy crypto? Same with you bro.. never buy from telegram accounts..